# Table sap.ui.table shows the same record

Tags: sapui5

I try to use this [table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting/preview).

But I can do what I want in the UI table are shown a lot of the same records. In the DB table I do have only one record. In my case I'm using a JSONModel and an Ajax Call through the DB.  The result of this call looks fine within the chrome console. There is only one record as I would expect. 
My first idea was that it must have something to do with the key. But there is a key. I really don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong.

```
result: {
  "data": [{
    "WirkstoffID": 1,
    "PatientID": "12",
    "PZN": 12101,
    "Wirkstoff": "stoff",
    "Wirkstaerke": "blabla"
  }]
}
```

**View**

```
 <t:Table class="sapUiContentPadding" height="496px" width="1092px" id="idTable" selectionMode="MultiToggle" rows="{modelWirkstoff>/0/}">
  <t:columns>

    <t:Column id="idPatientID" width="142px">
      <Text class="size12" text="PatientID" />
      <t:template>
        <Text text="{modelWirkstoff>/0/PatientID}" wrapping="false" />
      </t:template>
    </t:Column>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the table rows against the first entry instead of the array. The runtime does not complain abouts this and adds a column for every property it can determine. Below is a fixed example:

```
<t:Table rows="{modelWirkstoff>/result/data}">
    <t:columns>
        <t:Column id="idPatientID" width="142px">
            <Text class="size12" text="PatientID"/>
            <t:template>
                <Text text="{modelWirkstoff>PatientID}" wrapping="false"/>
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
    </t:columns>
</t:Table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave me the right direction. Was checking the coding again. "oModelWirkstoff.setData(result.data);" And changed the binding as you said against the array. rows="{modelWirkstoff>/}" > . Don't know why, thought I did also this before. But now I've understood where I've to take care when binding a table.